# What to use for Downloading Items in the Background

Tags: android, download, android-service, android-download-manager

Please pardon my ignorance, i am new to performing background task on an app when the app itself is in the background.

I am integrating a Download Manager into an App. We want the app to be able to listen when a downloadable url is copied or clicked and hence download the content directly. All without interacting with the app.

Service seem like the obvious choice but which one is appropriate use? 
i am targeting Android Pie [API 28] and minimum being Android Jelly Bean (API 16)

1. Service
2. Intent Service
3. Job Intent Service
4. Job Scheduler

According to docs Service (1) processes are performed on the main thread, which is disadvantage because users won't be able to simultaneously use the app while it's running.

Comment: Services are started on the main thread.  They can create whatever thread they want and then do processing on that.

Comment: @GabeSechan ok. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download files that takes too long time, use `download manager`. The `download manager` is a system service that handles long-running HTTP downloads. For more info refer to this page https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager